# FFMPEG command to apply echo effects

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

How to apply **echo** effect on a video (sound) using ffmpeg. Please advice me ffmpeg command for the same.

Comment: What did your research tell you? Did you search for "ffmpeg echo effect"? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [This might help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382676/audio-effects-in-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 6):

ffmpeg does have an echo filter

Usage is

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0 -c:v copy -af aecho=0.6:0.3:1000:0.5 output.mp4
```

The four parameters specified, separated by colons, are

> #### in_gain
>
> Set input gain of reflected signal. Default is 0.6.
>
> #### out_gain
>
> Set output gain of reflected signal. Default is 0.3.
>
> #### delays
>
> Set list of time intervals in milliseconds between original signal and reflections separated by ’|’. Allowed range for each delay is (0 -
>   90000.0]. Default is 1000.
>
> #### decays
>
> Set list of loudnesses of reflected signals separated by ’|’. Allowed range for each decay is (0 - 1.0]. Default is 0.5.